# Python: Look into the registry to find install location of a program

Tags: python, registry, key, winreg

I am trying to find the install location of a programme using the windows registry. I have managed to find the key and the value that I need. They are found in the *Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall* folder. However when I run the following script, it can't find the file.

```
from _winreg import *

aReg = ConnectRegistry(None,HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)

aKey = OpenKey(aReg, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall', 0, KEY_READ)

[Pathname,regtype]=(QueryValueEx(aKey,"InstallLocation"))

print Pathname

CloseKey(aKey)
CloseKey(aReg)
```

The Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\m.armstrong\Desktop\regression\regpy.py", line 7, in <module [Pathname,regtype]=(QueryValueEx(aKey,"InstallLocation"))
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

How is it that I can see the key but can't seem to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for the `InstallLocation` value of `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`.

You want the `InstallLocation` value of *some subkey under* `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`.

If you want a particular subkey, just add its name to that path.

If you want all of them, use the [`EnumKey`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html#_winreg.EnumKey) function. Something like this:

```
for i in itertools.count():
    try:
        subname = EnumKey(akey, i)
    except WindowsError:
        break
    subkey = OpenKey(akey, subname, 0, KEY_READ)
    pathname, regtype = QueryValueEx(subkey, "InstallLocation")
    print subname, pathname
    CloseKey(subkey)
```

Comment: What if I specify the exact program in aKey = OpenKey(aReg, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Andor SDK_is1', 0, KEY_READ). Will it find the install location for this progam only. I have tried and it returns the traceback as above.

Comment: @Marmstrong: Are you sure you got the name exactly right? Have you tried using `EnumKey` to see all the keys that are there, to see if it shows up?