# How can I check if a machine already has "miniconda" installed?

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, registry, nsis

I am trying to build an installer using NSIS.

That is however quite a new thing compared to everything else I did in the past when dealing with computers. As my program needs a conda environment to be executed, I am currently having the installer always download it and silently install it in a folder.

However, I realize that this may be very inefficient, as maybe the user of my software already has a compatible version of Anaconda installed somewhere. So, I would like to be able to check that, in the most general way possible, considering that another user may have installed his version of the software in a place that is not "default". How would I go about this?

I am learning about "registry key", but honestly, they still are a bit exoteric and mysterious to me. How can I learn/discover if a certain software has a corresponding registry key revealing his executable position? Does this even make sense as something registry keys are used fors?

Comment: Anaconda stores its install location in registry. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21090838/5541355) answer.

Comment: Thank you. From what I see, the miniconda keys there will also have their version, which I couldn't know beforehand. So I would need to iterate over all keys in `Current Version\Uninstall` and look up for `miniconda` strings in their names. Is that correct? Is that a typica solution?

Comment: It would help if you could link to the source code for the miniconda installer

Comment: Sure! Here you go [installer](https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe)

Comment: Oh, the SOURCE CODE of the miniconda installer...well...I don't know if I can have access to that...can I?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.